# Merging multiple csv files producing blank csv

Tags: php, csv

I'm currently trying to merge several .csv files with the following code:

```
<?php $csvdir = get_template_directory() . '/exports';
$csvcontent = '';
if (is_dir($csvdir)) {
    if ($handle = opendir($csvdir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
            if (substr($file, -4) === ".csv") {
                $csvcontent .= file_get_contents($csvdir . $file);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}

$result = fopen('app/merge.csv', 'w');
fwrite($result, $csvcontent);
fclose($result); ?>
```

It's outputting a blank csv file at the moment with no errors. Is there anything obvious wrong with the code?

The template to generate this is in the same directory as the exports folder.

Comment: Can you print `$csvcontent` inside the while loop right after reading file contents? Also, do you want to try adding `/` after `/exports` because when you are reading file content the path is becoming invalid I think.

Comment: Are you sure you actually go inside the `if`s? Try to add some echo statements after `if(is_dir()` and `$handle = readdir()`

Comment: i don't see anything obvious, have you tried sticking a few echo statements in to check that your ifs and whiles are triggering the way you expected? ie if is_dir($csvdir) returns false your code would never run which would explain the behaviour you're are seeing

Comment: @TobiasF. Nothing is outputting within the ifs so it's not getting that far. Would that be because the path to the exports is wrong?

Comment: @fiveelements good spot on the missing / in which case i will add that file_get_contents returns false if the file can't be read not an error

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As I have mentioned in the comment, you are missing `/` after the `exports` directory name. Hence, the file name is going wrong while reading contents from it.

Also, check the directory is a valid one by `echo $csvdir` and `echo is_dir($csvdir)` before the processing starts.

Here is the working demo: https://repl.it/@fiveelements/MergeCSVContents

And here is your modified code:

```
<?php $csvdir =  './exports/';
$csvcontent = '';
if (is_dir($csvdir)) {
    if ($handle = opendir($csvdir)) {
        while (($file = readdir($handle)) !== false) {
            if (substr($file, -4) === ".csv") {
                $csvcontent .= file_get_contents($csvdir . $file);
            }
        }
        closedir($handle);
    }
}
echo $csvcontent;
$result = fopen('exports/merge.csv', 'w');
fwrite($result, $csvcontent);
fclose($result); ?>
```

Comment: Cool thanks, think it was a combination of the path and reordering the code that sorted it out. Just need to strip the headers from each file but it works.